# Replacement for the DOA <di> tag

Tags: html, tags, definition, semantic-markup, xhtml2

The DOA (*or more appropriately, Dead **Before** Arrival*) XHTML2 working standard indicates support for [the `<di>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-list.html#sec_11.1.).

> [...] The term and its definition can be grouped within a `di` element to help clarify the relationship between a term and its definition(s).

To clarify, this tag would be used to group `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags together under a `<dl>`:

```
<dl>
    <di>
        <dt>defenestrate</dt>
        <dd>throw through or out of the window; "XHTML2 was defenestrated"</dd>
        <dd>what I will do if web standards keep going they way they are</dd>
    </di>
</dl>
```

Anyway, since `<di>` is out the window (*heh*), I was wondering what (*if any*) currently supported markup patterns could be described as semantically and structurally equivalent? I've essentially accepted that `<dl>` is not sufficient for my requirements (*as far as aesthetic requirements go*), so I'm on to looking at other solutions.

My intent for `<di>` was primarily a style hook<sup>1</sup>, as I'm using a definition list and intend to style the term/definition groupings as a single item.

For the sake of accessibility, I will be using the `aria-*` and `role` attributes to help define the relationship, but I'm hoping that there exists some generally accepted structure to emulate `<di>`, that I simply haven't encountered.

For example, I'm considering something like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <dfn id="term-1">term</dfn>
        <p aria-labelledby="term-1">definition for term 1</p>
        <p aria-labelledby="term-1">another definition for term 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <dfn id="term-2">term</dfn>
        <p aria-labelledby="term-2">definition for term 2</p>
        <p aria-labelledby="term-2">another definition for term 2</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

<sub>1. As I understand it, this is an oft-cited reason for its exclusion from HTML5 (*that it is merely a style hook*). Frankly, I think that's bull since it is a perfectly reasonable way to group terms and definitions for both aesthetic *and* parsing purposes. But who cares, right? Unquoted attributes and incomplete tags are far more important.`</sarcasm>`</sub>

Comment: <section> might suit the bill, but I don't think it would be valid within <dl>.

Comment: @Diodeus I've sort of accepted that `<dl>` won't work here, due to the child element constraints of only `<dt>` and `<dd>`. I can use a `<ul>` and do my best to define a relationship between the item parts; that's where I'm headed now. I'm just wondering if this problem has been tackled more formally, and has an existing solution.

Comment: The StackOverflow crowd isn't big on HTML semantic questions, I've found.

Comment: @Diodeus Well, either way I hope it's not an unwelcome question. I don't think its close-vote fodder, but I suppose it's *sort of* open ended. I'm just trying to find an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 CR defines a grouping within a [`dl` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), so that e.g. a `dd` element followed by one or more `dd` elements constitutes a group, the next `dd` starts a new group etc. In this sense, the `di` element would be structurally redundant. On the other hand, a `dl` element has really no semantics (beyond being structurally something), and there is no known software that processes it in any particular way, beyond default rendering issues.

If you wish to style such a group as a unit, you are mostly out of luck, as per specs and drafts. There is no proposal being considered about adding anything like `di`. You might submit a proposal, referring to `tbody` and `optgroup` as precedents (i.e. as special-purpose grouping elements within specific elements), but that would be a long way.

A short way is to use `div` for grouping inside `dl`. Of course it’s “invalid”, but that’s just a formal position, and browsers don’t really care. They seem to digest this fine:

```
<dl>
    <div>
        <dt>defenestrate</dt>
        <dd>throw through or out of the window; "XHTML2 was defenestrated"</dd>
        <dd>what I will do if web standards keep going they way they are</dd>
    </div>
    <div>
        <dt>pragmatic HTML</dt>
        <dd>using markup according to how things actually work in browsers
            and other relevant software</dd>
    </div>
</dl>
```

Browsers parse this so that `div` elements are children of the `dl` element, and the `dt` and `dd` elements still have their normal effect on default formatting.

And now you can style the units, e.g.

```
<style>
dl > div { border: solid red 1px; margin-bottom: 0.6em; }
</style>
```

You may get flamed for this. A safer, duller approach is to make each unit a separate `dl` element (and wrap the `dl` elements in a `div` container if you need to deal with the all of them as a single element).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've definitely considered the `dl > div > dt + dd` approach, however markup validity (*as valid as reasonably possible*) is unfortunately a requirement here. Blatant disregard for it isn't really an option, as much as I'd like it to be. I've also considered writing a proposal, but following through on that would probably leave me bald. Part of my target here is accessibility compliance, but unfortunately everyone wants to have their cake and eat it to, so I have the additional target of aesthetic qualities.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, because in today's landscape markup validity isn't very important (*Angular, et al*) and microdata formats provide orthogonal semantic structure. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, this is now official. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element (not sure exactly since when though.)